# How to change color of paper-tabs riple effect

Tags: css, polymer, polymer-1.0

im trying to learn Polymer, but i cannot understand how to style elements in version 1.0.
The exemple just show this..

> Custom property | Description | Default
>   ----------------|-------------|----------                                    `--paper-tabs-selection-bar-color` | Color for the selection bar |
>   `--paper-yellow-a100` `--paper-tabs` | Mixin applied to the tabs |
>   `{}`

But i cannot to undderstand wher i use this, or how i use. Someone can give me a basic example?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Polymer 1.0 introduced the concepts of custom CSS properties and custom CSS mixins.

[Custom CSS properties](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/styling.html#xscope-styling-details)

> Rather than exposing the details of an element’s internal
>   implementation for theming, instead an element author defines one or
>   more custom CSS properties as part of the element’s API.
>
> These custom properties can be defined similarly to other standard CSS
>   properties and will inherit from the point of definition down the
>   composed DOM tree, similar to the effect of `color` and `font-family`.

[Custom CSS mixins](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/styling.html#custom-css-mixins)

> It may be tedious (or impossible) for an element author to anticipate
>   and expose every possible CSS property that may be important for
>   theming an element as individual CSS properties (for example, what if
>   a user needed to adjust the `opacity` of the toolbar title?).
>
> For this reason, the custom properties shim included in Polymer
>   includes an experimental extension allowing a bag of CSS properties to
>   be defined as a custom property and allowing all properties in the bag
>   to be applied to a specific CSS rule in an element’s local DOM. For
>   this, we introduce a mixin capability that is analogous to `var`, but
>   allows an entire bag of properties to be mixed in.

Checkout the links to learn more.  Below you will find a simple example that contains the `paper-tabs` element and custom styles.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Paper Tabs Style Example</title>
    <script src="bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="import" href="bower_components/polymer/polymer.html" />
    <link rel="import" href="bower_components/paper-tabs/paper-tabs.html" />
    <style is="custom-style">
        :root {
            --my-custom-color: red;
            --paper-tab-ink: var(--my-custom-color);

            /* custom CSS property */
            --paper-tabs-selection-bar-color: blue;

            /* custom CSS mixin */
            --paper-tabs: {
                color: var(--default-primary-color); /* variable defined in default-theme.html */
                font-size: 20px;
            }
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <paper-tabs selected="0">
        <paper-tab>TAB 1</paper-tab>
        <paper-tab>TAB 2</paper-tab>
        <paper-tab>TAB 3</paper-tab>
    </paper-tabs>
</body>
</html>
```

Key parts to this example:

- For styles in the main document you can use [`<style is="custom-style">`](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/styling.html#custom-style).
- You can create your own custom CSS variables like `--custom-color: red;` and use them like `--paper-tab-ink: var(--custom-color);`.
- You can assign any valid, appropriate CSS to a defined *custom CSS property* like `--paper-tabs-selection-bar-color: blue;` or `--paper-tabs-selection-bar-color: rgba(0,255,0,0.5);`.
- Many elements include predefined CSS variables.  `paper-styles`, for example, includes `color.html` and `default-theme.html`.  These files define various CSS variables for colors that can be used to customize the style of elements.  `--default-primary-color` is one of these variables.  See below.

```css
/* custom CSS mixin */
--paper-tabs: {
    color: var(--default-primary-color); /* variable defined in default-theme.html */
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

Comment: It should be explained like this in the official docs imo. Thanks!